# Byte array to string conversion using groovy script in Mule 3.9

Tags: for-loop, groovy, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft

I am fetching datasets from redis(Get all from hash) cache and need to do the string comparison.
I am trying to use a **groovy** component inside **mule(3.9)** flow for having string comparison.
The payload, which is extracted from Redis is of type: Object(field=value pair), and I need to convert **Byte array to string** on all the payload values. I have done this conversion inside mule flow using 'Byte array to string' converter component, however, I would need to do this conversion using Groovy script.

The [payload.values()] is having values as below -

```
[B@5ef66f56
[B@2649bce9
[B@16e8e092
[B@9006e18
[B@64613cb1
[B@fa47a20
```

Can someone please help me get the groovy script to convert from **byte array to string**?
I chose to use Groovy since I need to break from for loop if I find a match. any better option? please suggest. 
[payloads from first 2 loggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hzm2.png)
Thanks

Comment: Please provide more detail here. Your source code, what you have already tried etc etc.

Comment: Welcome to StockOverflow @Deeps. Looks like you have the snippet shown above is inbetween the flow payload.  Post your flow and what output you are expecting. It will help people to answer you better.

Answer (score 0):

The most secret and not documented kung-fu to convert a `byte[]` into `String` is:

```
byte[] myBytes = ...
String myString = new String( myBytes )
```

or if you have a list of `byte[]`:

```
List<String> list = myListOfBytes.collect{ new String( it ) }
```